# Remove legend from a CartoDB layer

Tags: carto, legend

I am unable to remove the legend from a CartoDB layer. I have passed `legends: false` in `createLayer` options but with no luck. Below the code i used :

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, BikeTrails)

                .on('done', function(layer) {legends:false

                layerBikeTrails = layer;

L.control.layers(null, {
    'Dedicated Bike Lanes': layerBikeLanes, 
    'Bike Share Toronto': layerBikeShare, 
    'Bike Stores': layerBikeStores, 
    'Access to Multipurpose Trails': layerBikeTrails
})
.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not passing the layer options in the right place.

This should work:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, vizjson_url, { legends: false })
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer) {
   /* ... */
};
```

For more information, have a look to the [cartodb.js documentation](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that options is the third argument of createLayer:

```
var options = {
  legends: false
}

cartodb.createLayer(map, url, options).addTo(map);
```